# Would Stargate Command be affected by a US Government Shutdown?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1, politics

In the event of a US government shutdown, as occurred in 1995-1996, 2013, and 2018-2019, would Stargate Command be shut down? It's part of the US military, but it also employs a large number of civilians. And with it being secret, I'm not sure what would happen.

Unfortunately, *Stargate SG-1* takes place between 1997 and 2007, so it wasn't during a government shutdown. But based on the evidence we have of how it is run, would Stargate Command be affected by a US Government Shutdown?

Comment: i thought the IOA was in charge with funding (along with anything else Stargate related like command of the Atlantis mission) afterwards and that's multi-national isn't it?

Comment: @Memor IIRC the IOA only became a thing around season 5 or 6

Comment: Stargate Command was designed to be able maintain normal operations under extreme isolation and even Doomsday scenarios for great lengths of time. It’s  not likely any shutdown would go long enough for SGC really notice it

Comment: No more closing the IRIS. That takes too much energy. Just leave it open and keep troops at the gate ;) until the government opens again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The program is presumably in the [black budget](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_budget). The executive does not have to explain publicly where the money goes. So I would expect plenty of indirect effects, but no direct ones.

Comment: No food vendor services in the SG1 center cafeteria. All personnel are on their own for meals and to clean their workspaces. Would likely sum it up.

Comment: @MissouriSpartan, that assumes the food service are ordinary government workers, and not paid out of the same black budget as the rest of the facility. Otherwise some curious congresspeople might ask why there are cafeteria workers in a facility with no **office** workers. But that would only delay the problems -- who oversees the hiring of new ones if one of them retires?

Answer (score 2):

While I think the question may technically be out of the scope of this site the answer is a little bit of yes and a little bit of no.

During a shutdown essential government employees work without pay doing their essential jobs, they receive the pay they are due when the government reopens.  As active military is considered essential the base itself would remain operational and its probable that missions would continue possibly at a reduced rate the only real effect of a shutdown would be the possible furloughing of the civilian scientists although that would depend on how essential is defined.

On the other hand missions might be totally suspended and a Go'uld ship might manage to carpet bomb D.C hopefully while the parties argue about how much a servant of the people deserves to be paid (im aware the budget issues are more complicated than this)

Comment: In fact the budget issues are not about that whatsoever.

Comment: Maybe I should have put something else in the ()s but I didn't wanna cause a thing